# Link Papertrail and Heroku with CLI

Tags: heroku, papertrail-app

I have a Papertrail account on which I have several groups holding different systems (containing logs from docker containers, etc...). I would like to add a link between Papertrail and Heroku applications, which is doable by hand as described in this tutorial : http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/hosting-services/heroku/

However, I want to create the Papertrail-Heroku binding with command line in a script, so I want to get rid of the manual process described in "Method 2" of the tutorial.

The problem is that the "Method 1" automatically logs Heroku to a new Papertrail account, even if I change the config var PAPERTRAILER_API_TOKEN of Heroku to be the token of my previous Papertrail account : it doesn't work (am I doing something wrong, is it supposed to work ?).

I already use the papertrail-cli tools (https://github.com/papertrail/papertrail-cli) to create new systems and groups automatically, but I can't seem to create a system for Heroku since the papertrail-add-system cli accepts an ip or a port and it doesn't fit Heroku's requirements for logging.
When registering a new Heroku system on Papertrail thanks to the "Method 2" of the tutorial linked above, the manual process of creating a name for our system leads us to an URL like this: .papertrailapp.com:. However as said before, I cannot get this URL with a CLI.

What I do with the CLI for "normal" systems :

```
papertrail-add-group --group <group>
papertrail-add-system --system <system> [--hostname <hostname] --ip-address 1.2.3.4
papertrail-join-group --system <system> --group <group>
```

But there is nothing I can do like this for a Heroku binding:

```
papertrail-add-group --group <group>
papertrail-add-system --system <heroku_system> [--hostname <hostname] --ip-address <host>.papertrailapp.com:<port>
papertrail-join-group --system <heroku_system> --group <group>
```

Do you have any idea on how to achieve a Papertrail-Heroku binding with the CLI ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Papertrail. The log destination created by "Method 2" in the Heroku doc is not exposed in Papertrail's API (and thus is also not in the CLI). This API call is already pretty tough to understand, so we didn't want to make it even more complicated (especially without a consumer to design around).

There's at least a chance it could be added, though. Feel free to email Papertrail's support and explain a bit more about the app.